# how to refactor complicated if statement ruby

Tags: ruby, if-statement, refactoring

now i have if statement problem,
input.txt

`nobita,suneo,1992,1990,15-21,19-21
giant,sizuka,1120,1210,13-21
dorayaki,apple,1147,989,21-19,13-21,21-4`

Sometimes there are 2 
round, sometimes 3 rounds, or sometimes an invalid number of rounds (such as 1 or more 
than 3).

this my code

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach('input.txt', col_sep: ',') do |row|
  name1, name2, ro1, ro2 = row
  unless row[4]
      puts "no first-round match for #{name1} and #{name2}"
  else
      match1 = row[4]
      m1score1, m1score2 = row[4].split('-')
      if m1score1 > m1score2
          p "Match 1 #{name1} Win, #{name2} Lose"
      end
  end

  unless row[5]
      puts "there is no second round match for #{name1} v #{name2}"
  else
      match2 = row[5]
      m2score1, m2score2 = row[5].split('-')
      if m2score1 > m2score2
          p "Match 2 #{name1} Win, #{name2} Lose"
      end
  end

  unless row[6]
      puts "no third-round match for #{name1} and #{name2}"
  else
      match3 = row[6]
      m3score1, m3score2 = row[6].split('-')
      if m3score1 > m3score2
          p "Match 3 #{name1} Win, #{name2} Lose"
      end
  end
end
```

What must I do to be able to simplify the if statement?

Comment: I think the block accepts more than one argument. In this case, you can have arguments (name1, name2, x, y, *rounds). The argument *rounds will be an array. Later you can iterate rounds array.

Comment: Unless you're expecting `row` to contain `false` then tests for `nil?` are completely pointless. Instead just have `if row[0]`. You're creating double negatives here as the `else` clause is only triggered if the value is not *not* defined.

Comment: @tadman thanks about that, i will refactor

Comment: I'd recommend flipping the order of those blocks to avoid having a double-negative: `if/else/end` is preferable to `unless/else/end`. If you're used to languages like PHP, Perl and JavaScript where 0 and empty string are false, Ruby has only two logically false values: `nil` and `false`. You can shrink your code considerably if the `false` case is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Does the input have to be a CSV? Since the rows are varying lengths, I'd recommend a different structure like json or something (if possible).

If it has to be CSV, but you can make the assumption that a row with a certain length will always have the correct data for that length, then you can just look at the row's length to see what you should do.

For example, your rows are 6, 5, 7 in length respectively. If a row with a length of 6 always has the data in the same order, then you could just do

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach('input.txt', col_sep: ',') do |row|
    DataHandler.handle(row)
end

class DataHandler
  def self.handle(row)
    case row.length
    when 5
      # do stuff when a row has 5 cols
    when 6
      # do stuff when a row has 6 cols
    when 7
      # do stuff when a row has 7 cols
    end
  end
end
```

The issue here would come in if, for example, you had a missing inner column. In which case, it would be better to have placeholders to make them all the same length like

```
apple, ball, cat, 123, 456
thing, this,    , 678, 543
other, blah, dog,    ,
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach('input.txt', col_sep: ',') do |row|
  name1, name2, ro1, ro2, *matches = row
  matches.each_with_index do |match, idx|
      m1score1, m1score2 = match.split('-')
      if m1score1.to_i > m1score2.to_i
          p "Match #{idx} #{name1} Win, #{name2} Lose"
      end
  end
  if matches.count < 3
    puts "there were only #{matches.count} matches for #{name1} and #{name2}"
  end
end
```

I assume of course that if there was a second match it necessarily means that there was a first round, etc...

Also, I've taken the liberty to add `.to_i` to `m1socre` and `m2score` since `"3" > "29"`...

Comment: what *matches mean ? i never meet that syntax before.

Comment: it's called a [splat](https://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/). It is assigned the rest of the array.

Comment: thanks for the splat
hey, can you give me refactor code again? I just wrote a mistake in my code above

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @BowoKeren

Comment: sorry for my bad english. I just change my code above,
where each match making its own variables, please check.

Comment: @BowoKeren - as far as I understand your code, I suspect the variables you set are inside the scope of the `if` - which means you won't be able to see them outside the `if`. How do you intend to use them afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

I tried refactoring by creating a class for `Match`. You could further refactor by adding a `Round` class.

```
require 'csv'

class Match
  def initialize(row)
    @player_1, @player_2, @ro1, @ro2, *@rounds = row 
  end

  def get_round(index)
    @rounds[index-1]
  end

  def to_s
    result = "#{@player_1} v #{@player_2}\n"
    (1..3).each do |index|
      if round = get_round(index)
        m1score1, m1score2 = round.split('-')
        if m1score1.to_i > m1score2.to_i
          result += "    Match #{index}: #{@player_1} Wins over #{@player_2}\n"
        end
      else
        result += "    No #{index} round match\n"
      end
    end
    return result
  end
end

CSV.foreach('input.txt', col_sep: ',') do |row|
  match = Match.new(row)
  puts match.to_s + "\n"
end
```